# Excel Custom Ribbon Group - Special Characters in the label

Tags: excel, special-characters, ribbonx

I have a custom Ribbon with buttons in Excel. I use XML below...
Is there a way to use special characters: an ampersand or quotation marks in the description (label)?

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false"> 
    <tabs> 
      <tab id="CustomTab" label="Custom"> 
        <group id="TransactionFilter" label="Transaction Sort and Filter"> -- I would like "Transaction Sort & Filter"
          <button id="bSetFilter" imageMso="Filter" size="large" 
                  label="Filter" 
                  onAction="SetFilterFromRibbon"/> 
          <button id="bClearFilter" imageMso="FilterClearAllFilters" size="large" 
                  label="Clear Filter" 
                  onAction="ClearFilterFromRibbon"/> 
        </group> 
      </tab> 
    </tabs> 
  </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

I have tried repeating the character twice, putting a star in front of it. Nothing worked so far

Answer (score 2):

Note: Double `&amp;` are needed.

```
label="Quotation&quot;"
label="Ampersand&amp;&amp;"
```

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you sir!

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it solves your question. It's helpful for other SO users.